# Why is this.props.counter null?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-saga

src/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import combineReducers from './reducers';
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import CustomCounter from './add'
import mySaga from './sagas';
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {combineReducers},
  middleware: [sagaMiddleware],
})

sagaMiddleware.run(mySaga);  
 
const container = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <CustomCounter />
  </Provider>
);
```

src/add/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { increate, increateAsync } from '../actions';

export class CustomCounter extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>:{this.props.counter}</p>
        <button onClick={()=>this.props.increate()}>自增</button>
        <button onClick={()=>this.props.increateAsync()}>异步自增</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    counter: state.counter
  }
}
  
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { increate, increateAsync })(CustomCounter);
```

src/sagas/index.js

```js
import { all } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { add } from './counter';

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    add()
  ])
}
```

src/sagas/counter.js

```js
import { put, takeEvery, delay } from 'redux-saga/effects';

function* increase() {
  yield delay(3000); 
 
  yield put({ type: 'INCREMENT' });
}

export function* add() {
  yield takeEvery('INCREMENT_ASYNC', increase);
}
```

src/reducers/index.js

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import counter from './counter';

export default combineReducers({
  counter
})
```

src/reducers/counter.js

```js
const counter = (state = 1, action = {}) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return state + 1;
        
    default:
      return state
  }
}
  
export default counter;
```

src/actions/index.js

```js
export const increate = () => {
  return {
    type: 'INCREMENT'
  }
}  
  
export const increateAsync = () => {
  return {
    type: 'INCREMENT_ASYNC' ,   
  }
}
```

My problem is, in `src/add/index.js` I want the page to display `this.props.counter` but `this.props.counter` is always null and cannot display the result. I want the page to display the calculation result of `this.props.counter` and the initial value 1.

Comment: Just as a FYI, as it seems that you are learning React, Redux and Saga right now: You are using a *very* outdated style of React (the ecosystem moved away from class components in 2019) and Redux (you should be using Redux Toolkit for everything, not writing ACTION_TYPES or switch..case reducers by hand, also since 2019). The Redux team also recommends against Redux Saga in most cases nowadays.
Please check that you are following up-to-date tutorials!

Answer (score -1):

## Issue

The combined reducer function that includes the `count` state is imported as `combineReducers`:

src/reducers/index.js

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import counter from './counter';

export default combineReducers({
  counter
});
```

src/index.js

```js
import combineReducers from './reducers';
```

But when configuring the store is passed in a way that nests the reducer function/state in a property also named `combineReducers`:

src/index.js

```js
...
import combineReducers from './reducers';
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
...

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    combineReducers // <-- nested
  },
  middleware: [sagaMiddleware],
});
```

So instead of the expected `state.counter` being available it is actually `state.combineReducers.counter`.

src/add/index.js

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    counter: state.counter // <-- not defined
  };
};
```

## Solution

Pass the combined reducer function ***as*** the root reducer.

Example:

src/index.js

```js
...
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import rootReducer from './reducers';
...

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => 
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(sagaMiddleware),
});
```